# Titanium [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination

Tags: titanium

I am trying to run default example apps in titanium studio, but I am getting error.
I installed jdk1.6.0_45, jre1.6.0 and set the properties of Environment Variables too.
what was the problem, any suggetions?

[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Comment: Can you build from within the Titanium Studio?  I'm having the same issue.  My workaround, I built the apk from within the IDE then installed it on to a device from the command line to test it.  Seems like we're not alone based on a Google search for that error message limiting results to those in the Past Month.  Appcelerator's jira has a number of entries as well as their developer center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed all required Android SDKs? If you are using latest Titanium SDK, you need to install Android SDK 2.3.3 (API 10). Check more details in [Installing the Android SDK guid in Titanium documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Android_SDK).

If this won't help set console log level to `trace` and update question with full error log.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the 32-bit version of Java JDK is required regardless of whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit system.

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Quick_Start