# Appcelerator Titanium error: Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: android, titanium, emulation, appcelerator

I almost lost my mind, I have spent 3 days trying to fix this. I have Windows 7 64 Bits, I have installed the jdk for 32 bits, I have installed the following Android SDK's: 2.3.3, 3.0, 4.1.2 and 4.3. Also I have set the variable ANDROID_SKD to the right path, etc. I really don't know what else to do.

I have already done this: [Titanium [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897955/titanium-error-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination)

I would appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [This Link](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix). And try to use JDK 6 not JDK 7, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they still only support JDK 6 32 bit with Titanium Studio 3.3.0 (latest right now), different to what they say here http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-SupportedSDKReleases (that they support jdk 8).

At least for me, JDK 7/8 32 bit led to crashes. Have to search a bit on the Oracle site.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR

I was able to have both jdk 8 64bit and jdk 6 32bit installed in parallel.

I also now start with batch file

```
set ANDROID_SDK=C:\android-sdk-win
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45
set PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;%PATH%
"C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Appcelerator\Titanium Studio\TitaniumStudio.exe" &
```

Like described in some posts at appcelerator website, like http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/146294/program-launch-failed-unable-to-locate-java-vm-please-set-javahome-environment-variable .