# Getting JDK related error with Titanium Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, sdk, titanium

I am running a Titanium app on my Ubuntu, which is been developed on Mac with Titanium SDK 3.3.0 and JDK 1.6.

Now when I am trying to run the same project on my Ubuntu 13.04 on the Titanium studio with 3.2.3 and JDK 1.7 . The app is crashing. this looks similar to [this](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/163212/application-installer-abnormal-process-termination-process-exit-value-was-8-titanium) error

And when I am selecting the SDK as 3.3.0 I am getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145571/appcelerator-titanium-error-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination) error.

So with these two problems, the solution could be to downgrade from 1.7 to 1.6 JDK If I want to use 3.3.0 Titanium SDK.

**So my question is, Is there anyway with which I can start my Titanium studio to start with Jdk 1.6?**

Similar questions have been asked but not the exact one, like I am facing 2 different problems when I switch to the Titanium SDK. Please help.